# figuring out what customers bought together with the most popular product in graph database

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql, graph-databases, nosql-aggregation

I am using Neo4j.
The schema for the database is:

```
MATCH (customer{customerid})-[:made]->(purchased{invoiceno, invoicedate})-[:includes{quantity, invoiceamount}]->(product{stockcode, unitprice})
```

I already know how to get the most popular product.

```
MATCH (a:customer)-[r1:made]->(b:purchase)-[r2:includes]->(c:product)
RETURN p.stockcode, count(*) AS quantity
ORDER BY quantity DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Which gives me the the most popular product.

```
╒══════════════╤═══════════════════╕
│"p.stockcode" │"quantity"         │
╞══════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│"85123A"      │77                 │
└──────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

how do I tell what customer bought together with this product.

Answer (score 0):

The query to get a list of the stockcodes of products purchased with your most popular stock and the number of times they were purchased with the most popular item would be something like:

```
MATCH (pr:product{stockcode:"85123A"})<-[includes]-(pu:purchase)-[includes]->(pr2:product)
RETURN pr2.stockcode, count (*) as quantity
```